# How can I filter hidden fields from an HtmlDocument object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have loaded an `HtmlDocument` using `HtmlWeb`. I understand I can get all the hidden input fields using the `SelectNodes()` method. But I don't want to get all the hidden input like "__VIEWSTATE" or "__EVENTTARGET". how can i filter them?

Code:

```
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

    HtmlNodeCollection hiddenFieldNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[@type='hidden']");
```

Edit:
Is there any XPath I can apply to filter among hidden input fields?

Comment: //input[not(@type='hidden')]

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore any of the Asp.NET special hidden fields, with the following `xpath`. All of their special fields have names starting with two underscores:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(url);

HtmlNodeCollection visibleFieldNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input[not(starts-with(@name, '__'))]");
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clear that up. Its not that I don't want the hidden input fields. I just don't want them all i.e. "__VIEWSTATE". I need to filter among them. So is there any xpath for that I can apply?

Comment: is it only the asp.net ones yours not interested in? (they all start with __) or is it a certain list you want to ignore

Comment: @nazmoonnoor does this now remove all the input fields you don't want? or are there other ones you want to filter out? This removes the inputs auto-added by ASP.NET